# Using selenium driver.find_element().click() on a subdivided webpage

Tags: python, selenium

First of all, I'm completely new in web scraping, html and selenium, so my question might not seem meaningful to you.

**What I'm trying to do:** automated click on an image on a webpage. Manual click on this image allows to display new information on a part of the webpage.

**How I tried to do it:**  I found something specific to this image, for example:

```
<img src="images/btn_qmj.gif" border="0">
```

So I just entered in python:

```
xpath = '//img[@src="images/btn_qmj.gif"]'
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
```

**Problem:** this returns me an empty list. I partially understood why, but I don't have any solution.

[image of the html code inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRd1I.png)

I included here an image of the html tree I obtain on the web inspector. As one can see, the tree to reach my line of interest gives "/html/frameset/frame[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRd1I.png)/**#document**/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/img".
The issue is that I cannot access -by using an xpath- anything that comes after the #document. If I try to copy the xpath of my line of interest, it tracks it back only up to the 2nd "/html". It is like the page is subdivided, compartmentalized, with inner parts I cannot access. I suppose there is a way to access the #document content, maybe it refers to another webpage, but I'm stuck at that point.
I would be very grateful if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: Might be a bit easier to help if you could share the webpage URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried switching to the frame first?

```
driver.switch_to.frame('gauche')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch control to frame first to handle image on it. Please see below code for your reference

```
 driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "'//img[@src="images/btn_qmj.gif"]'"))).click()
 driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

**Note** ::  You need to add below imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you also for your answer! This switch_to_frame is very powerful.

Comment: I would be glad to do it, but is it possible to do it for more than one answer? Because I already did something similar for the first answer I received.

Comment: Yes you can doo it without any issue. My code is very clear and I have also added explicit wait including switch back to parent window

Answer (score 0):

The element is present inside an `iframe`.In order to access the element you need to switch it first.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"gauche")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@src='images/btn_qmj.gif']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks for answering too! It's very helpful!

Comment: @Barth33 : Glad to help you!!! Always use explicit wait while interacting with web elements.Thanks.